# MVC 5 & Bootstrap 3.3.5

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

A few days ago I started a project in MVC 5. I upgrade Twitter bootstrap up to 3.3.5 version. The problem is when I've got error, the element which visualised it, does not have any CSS. Here is the element:

```
    <div id="status" class="alert alert-error">....</div>
```

But when I inspect element and change "alert-error" to "alert-danger" the CSS work. Can you tell me where is the problem. I am using Twitter Bootstrap 3.3.5 v., should I downgrade it or not. And how to solve the problem.

Comment: I don't know your previous bootstrap version but current versions use classes like alert-danger, alert-info, alert-warning, alert-success etc.. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts

Comment: Yes i know this, but i do not know how to change MVC to add "alert-danger" class to elements

Comment: How are you rendering the element? Is the code that you've posted the actual code from the `cshtml` file?

Comment: The code is rendering using Razor engine, i took the code from browser not from cshtml

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap does not define `alert-error`. Here are the alert classes that you may use:

- alert-success,
- alert-info,
- alert-warning,
- alert-danger.

You can find the more about them [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts).

**NB:** You do not need to "change MVC" to add a class to an element -- just edit your view (.cshtml) as a normal text file. That simple!

Comment: I was blind all the time, i found my mistake and now it works. Thank you.